# yii2 Image::thumbnail error: Unable to open image

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to make a thumbnail of an imagen using `Image::thumbnail` of `yii\imagine\Image` and I always have the same error: `Unable to open image`. I've been trying to set full path to achieve it but always raise the same error.

For example:

`Image::thumbnail('<my personal path>/web/uploads/resources/5fd34269ab821.jpg', 400, 400)`

I changed the permission of the folder and the image directly, but nothings works. I think that problem can be other. Any sugestion?

Comment: open `Image` class and find this function `thumbnail`, see where it throw this error, what is purpose of code, and what parameters function recieves

Comment: Finally it wasn't the problem. Thanks anyway. Deep dive into the code help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Finally in my case the problem wasn't the code. Was the images, for some reason the images which I was working was corrupt. With others the code was fine.

So, by the way, I found very useful catch errors that Imagen::thumbnail raised behind the scenes, so, in the method `createImageFromString` almost the last step to open the image, I changed a little bit the code to know a bit more:

```
    private function createImageFromString(&$string)
    {
        return ErrorHandling::ignoring(0, function () use (&$string) {
            //  imagecreatefromstring() does not support webp images before PHP 7.3.0
            if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70300 && function_exists('imagecreatefromwebp') && $this->isWebP($string)) {
                return @imagecreatefromwebp('data:image/webp;base64,' . base64_encode($string));
            }
            try {
                $a = @imagecreatefromstring($string);
                if (!$a =@imagecreatefromstring($string)) {
                    $e = error_get_last();
                    die($e['message']);
                }
                return $a;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        });
    }
```

And finally I saw it other differnt error, that helped me to find the problem:

`imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format`

Maybe it could be help others. Thanks for the help.